# What do these special spaces do in Elefant Hunt?

Tags: untagged

I recently dug up a very old Tom Wham board game that I cut out of a Dragon Magazine back in the 1980s (I want to say early 80s) called Elefant Hunt. I have all the pieces, and I remember the mechanics surprisingly well enough that I think I can play it without the rule book. I am just stuck on two spaces on the board: the Lost City and the Elefant Graveyard. I believe this is where you get relic and ivory counters, but I don't know how many or for how many points. Does anyone know the rules governing these two spaces on the board?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the board, highlight these two spaces?

Comment: is it this game: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3925/elefant-hunt

Comment: That is the game and although you did not post an answer, your comment is helpful because it tells me what issue of Dragon the game was in. I can now search my boxes for that one, or try to find a copy on line to get the full rules. So thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've located Dragon #88 online and have printed out the rules. I'm going to go ahead and post this answer because the answer I originally accepted was incomplete.

It was correct insofar as you gain one ivory when landing on the Elefant Graveyard and one relic when landing on the Lost City. It was also correct in that these items could be traded in at either port for 3d6 points, each.

What the answer failed to mention is that when landing on the Elefant Graveyard, you lose one captured elephant, if you have one. Likewise, when landing on the Lost City, you lose one of your hired hunters (chosen randomly), if you have one. It does not specify choosing the elephant randomly in the Graveyard, so presumably the player may choose to lose a normal elephant if he also has the higher-point value Mad Mom.

Presumably, you cannot take a relic or ivory if none are in the bank, but the game comes with so many that, given the limitations on movement and the incentive to cash these items in as soon as possible, this is extremely unlikely to ever occur.

Answer (score 2):

They score 3d6 points when returned to port.

From the rules:

> When a player lands on the Elefant Graveyard, he
> takes an Ivory marker. When he lands in the Lost City,
> he takes a Relic marker. Ivory and Relics are worth a
> variable number of points upon their return to port, as
> determined by a roll of three dice.

> The value of each Relic and piece of Ivory is determined by totalling the roll of three dice.